# getScript jQuery path not working / Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, getscript

I've got a jQuery function that is called after a doubleclick on a list item.

**app/assets/javascripts/tile/tile.js**

```
$('#list > li').dblclick(function(){
  // styling
  $(this).toggleClass('liked');

  // pass ID to controller
  var movie_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $.getScript("/likes.js");
});
```

Next to applying some new formats to said item my main goal is to make a database entry from my `like` controller. In this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes?view=comments) the `index` action from their `comments` controller gets called with this simple line.

```
$.getScript("/comments.js");
```

Additionally some JavaScript gets called from a `index.js.erb` file.

My first problem with understanding the example code from Railscasts is how they define the action. If I wanted to call the action `createLike` from my `likes_controller` how would I call it?

Secondly, my attempts so far have all failed because both the JavaScript file doesn't load and the action doesn't get called aswell.

Somehow I sense that I've messed up with the paths. Where should I locate the JavaScript files that should get called with the `getScript` function?

### Files

**app/assets/javascripts/likes/index.js.erb**

```
console.log("Test");
```

**app/controllers/likes_controller.rb**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery

  def index
    Like.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :item_id => params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking...do you want to use AJAX calls in order to send\receive information from the server?

Comment: I won't be able to try all your great suggestions until Thursday... Thanks already for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the execution issue can be solved by moving index.js.erb from

**app/assets/javascripts/likes/index.js.erb**

to

**app/views/likes**

This is where Rails looks for templates to render (your script shouldn't be served by the asset pipeline).  Rails tackles this through convention - your app automatically routes /likes to the index action.

If you want a more informative route, use the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to generate a new route and match it to the create_likes action in the Likes controller.  Then,
    $.getScript("/create_likes.js") 
will know where to look

Comment: Thanks allot, this worked for me! :) After changing the path of the JS file I had to add `resources :likes` to my routes so that it would match `GET /likes` with the `index` action.

Answer (score 2):

You can define action in controller like that:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  # another code
  def createLike
    # your action code
  end
  # another code
end
```

And you can call action like `/likes/createLike`.
In the folder `PATH_TO_APP/app/views/likes` create a file `createLike.html.erb` - there is will be a `createLike` view

Javascript files must be in the folder `/PATH_TO_APP/public/javascripts`
And best way to include javascript file is a [javascript_include_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/JavascriptTagHelpers/javascript_include_tag) like:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "tile/tile.js" %>
```

`tile.js` file must be is into the `/PATH_TO_APP/public/javascripts/tile` directory.

And if you want to get javascript files with jQuery, you must put them in `public/javascripts` directory and call `$.getScript('/javascripts/likes.js');` - there is an example.

**P.S.** I advise to look at [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're wanting is different than what that specific Railscasts is addressing. It is specifically focused on the retrieving of new comments as they are created, without a page refresh. That is why you are running into issues following this guide.

First you will need to make sure you have a `resources :likes` in your config/routes.rb. From your code excerpt it looks like you are associating a like with a movie so make sure you make the route nested inside your `resources :movies` call. In the end your routes should look something like this:

```
resources :movies do
  resources :likes
end
```

For the controller piece you will need to add a 'create' action to your controller. Assuming that your Movie model `has_many :likes` this is a simple version of what your action should look like:

```
def create
  movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
  movie.likes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

You will also need to change your javascript code to make a post instead of a get request. That's because the http method is how Rails differentiates between a create and an index request as they both use the same url path (e.g. /comments.js). You will also need to have the url reflect that it's a nested resource within a movie. Here is modified version of your JS code with that change:

```
$('#list > li').dblclick(function() {
  // Cached jquery this selector.
  $this = $(this)

  // pass ID to controller
  var movie_id =  $this.data('id');
  $.post('/movies/' + movie_id + '/likes.js', function() {
    $this.toggleClass('liked');
  });
});
```

In regards to your .js.erb file, as stated by others, it should be placed in your `app/views` folder. However, due to your regular JS handling the logic you don't need to have it all.

This is just one strategy but there are quite a few other ways to handle JS interaction with Rails. If you want an example of using a js.erb (js.coffee in this case) view file you can take a look at this [implementation](https://github.com/gmanley/soshigal/blob/master/app/views/comments/create.js.coffee). In that case all that is handling the click event is a link_to with the remote: true option which delegates it the jquery-ujs adapter.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

This might not be close to your answer but I use `$.getscript()` to load those `js/css` files that i need once my page has rendered,which in turn improves the performance and reduces the page load time.This is the code I have used in my `erb` files.My shop_for_free_module.js resides in `app/public/javascripts`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        //this gives your protocol-http
        var protocol = this.location.protocol;
        //this gives your domain name-myshopptinsite.com
        var host = this.location.host;
        var initial_url = protocol + "//" + host;
        $.getScript(initial_url + "/javascripts/eshop_js/shop_for_free_module.js");
    });
</script>
```

...hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

try this out

Question: My first problem with understanding the example code from Railscasts is how they define the action. If I wanted to call the action createLike from my likes_controller how would I call it?

Answer:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

  def create_like
    Like.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :item_id => params[:id])
  end
end
```

in routes.rb file

```
get '/create_like.js' => 'likes#create_like'
```

Question: Secondly, my attempts so far have all failed because both the JavaScript file doesn't load and the action doesn't get called aswell.

Anaswer: move app/assets/javascripts/likes/index.js.erb

code to

app/views/likes/create_like.js.erb

you need to pass item_id to

getScript method

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#list > li').dblclick(function(){
  // styling
  $(this).toggleClass('liked');

  // pass ID to controller
  var item_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $.getScript("/create_like.js?item_id=" + item_id);
});
});
```

Comment: @TheChamp updated my answer, fixed a code bug in calling getScript method, instead of likes.js create_like.js must be called.